# Quick CPU ring mode protection question

Tags: windows, hardware, driver, cpu

I am very curious in messing up with HW. But my top level "messing" so far was linked or inline assembler in C program. If my understanding of CPU and ring mode is right, I cannot directly from user mode app access some low level CPU features, like disabling interrupts, or changing protected mode segments, so I must use system calls to do everything I want.

But, if I am right, drivers can run in ring mode 0. I actually don´t know much about drivers, but this is what I ask for. I just want to know, is learning how to write your own drivers and than call them the way I should go, to do what I wrote?

I know I could write whole new OS (at least to some point), but what I exactly want to do is acessing some low level features of HW from standart windows application. So, is driver the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer: Managing access to low-level hardware features is exactly the job of the OS kernel and if you only want access to a single feature there's no need to start your own OS from scratch. Most modern OSes, such as WIndows, Linux, or the BSDs, allow you to add code to the kernel through kernel modules.

When writing a kernel module (or device driver), you write code that is going to be executed inside the OS kernel and will thus be running in CPU ring 0. Great power comes with great responsibility, which in this case means that you should really know what you're doing as there will be no pre-configured OS interface to prevent you from doing the wrong things. You should therefore study the manuals of your hardware (e.g., Intel's x86 software developer's manuals, device specs, ...) as well as standard operating systems development literature (where you're also going to find plenty on the web -- [OSDev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page), [OSDever](http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/index), [OSR](http://www.osronline.com/index.cfm), [Linux Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play with HW write some programs for 16-bit real-mode (or even with your own transition to protected-mode). There you have to deal with ASM, BIOS interrupts, segments, video memory and a lot of other low-level stuff.